# How to handle error on outlined edit text checking regex in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have this outlined edit text, and I want to display a red error color when user tries to put `'@'` on the outline edit text when they're trying to sign in. I was wondering how I can handle error on an edit text in jetpack compose

```
UserInputTextField(
                    fieldState = usernameState.value,
                    onFieldChange = { usernameState.value = it },
                    label = "Enter Name",

                    )

@Composable
fun UserInputTextField(
    fieldState: String,
    onFieldChange: (String) -> Unit,
    label: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField(
        value = fieldState, onValueChange = {
            onFieldChange(it)
        },
        label = { androidx.compose.material.Text(text = label) },
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 16.dp)
            .semantics { testTag = TestTags.LoginContent.USERNAME_FIELD },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = Color.Blue,
            unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Black
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isError` attribute of `TextField`.

**Example**

```
isError = fieldState.contains("@"),
```

---

**Sample code for reference**

```
@Composable
fun ErrorCheck() {
    val (text, setText) = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    UserInputTextField(
        fieldState = text,
        onFieldChange = setText,
        label = "Email",
    )
}

@Composable
fun UserInputTextField(
    fieldState: String,
    onFieldChange: (String) -> Unit,
    label: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextField(
        value = fieldState,
        onValueChange = {
            onFieldChange(it)
        },
        isError = fieldState.contains("@"),
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(
                all = 16.dp,
            ),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = Color.Blue,
            unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Black,
        )
    )
}
```